# buy button cart different from store cart

Tags: shopify, cart

I am using shopify lite and I have a question about its store cart vs its buy button carts. When I add a buy button to our squarespace site, the shopping cart for that product will add to whatever other products are in the cart (As expected). But when I use the url for a product in the online store, it adds that product to a separate cart.

I want shoppers to be able to use the buy buttons and the online store pages to add products to the same cart. Is there any way to do this with code? I assume there is, I've used custom code in our site but I'm not an expert coder. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance